# Wordpress for Video streaming site?

Tags: wordpress, video-streaming, html5-video

How would you rate wordpress in terms of stability/able to handle traffic when it comes to having a video streaming website?

How much better/worse is it than having a web application built from the ground up?
Is it an acceptable compromise for "starters" before I have an application built from the ground up? Say, 100 people streaming at once.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any HTML page can show a streaming video :), so there is nothing wrong to make wordpress to show streaming videos. Ability to handle traffic depends on where your 'wordpress' is being hosted, and wordpress *DOES NOT* decide on how many users/hits it can take or how much video it can show to users.

Please clarify what you mean by "100 people streaming at once". Do you mean 100 people watching the stream, or pushing a stream via wordpress UI into a streaming server ? Again, wordpress has nothing to do both, if you embed a 'video' in a wordpress, millions of people can watch it, if the hosted video file is placed in a CDN (content delivery network), it all depends on where you "place" your video file. As long as the place you host your video file, have lots of bandwidth, and processor resources, you wouldnt face an issue, and wordpress has nothing to do with anything.